# Hibernate 4.3.5 to 4.0.1 Exception org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat, weblogic, java-7

I am working on moving the application from Tomcat 8 to Weblogic 10.3.6. Technology Stack we are using:

1. Spring : 4.1.5.RELEASE
2. Hibernate : 4.3.5
3. Database : Postgres

In Tomcat 8 application is working good, but when I try to deploy on Weblogic 10.3.6, all started failing as application is using JPA 2.1. On Weblogic 10.3.6 by default it supports JPA 1 and there is a Patch for JPA 2.

Now to fit our application, I am trying to move back to JPA 2.0 by taking down Hibernate 4.3.5 to 4.0.1.

And removed "javax.persistence.Transactional" and "CriteriaDelete" from the code.

Now I am trying to deploy the code in Weblogic, I am getting "Out of memory", which I will fix latter.

Later I tried deploying the code in Tomcat 8, it is throwing an exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: abc] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:889)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateEjbPersistenceProvider.java:51)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1625)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1562)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
    at org.hibernate.loader.BasicLoader.postInstantiate(BasicLoader.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.<init>(EntityLoader.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.BatchingEntityLoader.createBatchingEntityLoader(BatchingEntityLoader.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2323)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createEntityLoader(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2346)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.createLoaders(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3612)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.postInstantiate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3598)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.postInstantiate(SingleTableEntityPersister.java:1013)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:422)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1737)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 27 more
```

Please note that the application was working good, before downgrade of Hibernate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this. It is basically due to multiple fetchtype.Eager in the entity class which is creating the problem. You can find full information about the fix in 
"http://blog.eyallupu.com/2010/06/hibernate-exception-simultaneously.html"